# Online Game Login Design

Tags: mysql, algorithm, go

I am currently working on an online game and I have a design problem with the `login server`. Each player must only be logged-in from one client, if he tries to open another client and tries to login it should tell that the account is already logged in from another client.

That works, but the problem is when someone tries to login from 2 clients at the exact same time both clients go through, causing the account to be logged-in in 2 different places. Which is something I do not wan't.

My current approach is like (I'm using GoLang):

```
var onLogin map[string]uint16 = make(map[string]uint16)

func login(data []byte) []byte {
    username := cstring(data[8:23])
    password := cstring(data[24:39])

    // check if already trying to login
    _, loggingIn := onLogin[username]
    if loggingIn {
        fmt.Println("Possible double connect attempt", username)
        return nil
    }

    (...check if correct login info...)
    (...check if user is already logged in...)

    // remove from list before returning
    delete(onLogin, username)

    (...build and send back packet to client if login success or fail...)
```

It helps (A BIT) but when someone is able to press the LOGIN button on 2 clients at inhumanly exact same time it still goes through. Maybe my design is flawed? Any advice? Cheers!

Comment: Not  familiar with golang, but in any sensible language one would use a mutex to serialize logins, i.e. only allow one login at a time.

Comment: There's a race around the map. You need to provide a mutex in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onLogin` needs a mutex, if you run your code with `-race` it will tell you there's a race.

[Race Detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector) is a must read.

// edit example:

```
var onLogin = struct {
    sync.Mutex
    m map[string]bool
}{m: map[string]bool{}}

func login(data []byte) []byte {
    username := cstring(data[8:23])
    password := cstring(data[24:39])
    onLogin.Lock()
    defer onLogin.Unlock()

    if _, loggingIn := onLogin.m[username]; loggingIn {
        fmt.Println("Possible double connect attempt", username)
        return nil
    }
    ///....
}
```

Comment: Uhmmm, makes sense, I know how a mutex works. But I've never tried using it. I'll do some research, will come back with results. New to mutexes.

Comment: Also, simultaneous writes to a map, or writes at the same time as reads, can outright crash.

Comment: @majidarif I added a very simple example to get you started.

Comment: Hello, I saw `streamrail/concurrent-map` on github and I'm using it now. Will still have to test if it improved anything. Thanks.